# Has anyone built a tabstrip control for Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, navigation

Obviously there are some proprietary controls such as Telerik, Syncfusion and Component Art - but I was wondering if anyone had attempted to build this type of control from scratch? I thought of overloading the tab control in silverlight 2? Anyone have any pointers?

Comment: I've actually found this article which may help!! 

http://www.rickdoes.net/post/2009/11/06/WPF-Single-Row-Tab-Control.aspx

Comment: Althought that is for WPF! Trying to see if I can modify it for Silverlight!

Comment: Whats wrong with the existing TabControl?

Comment: When you add too many child items to the tab control for the visible area it will wrap around similar to the functionality you expect say in a windows tab. What I am asking about is a tab strip which does not wrap around and has scrollable buttons (or tabs) which can cycle through each tab. 

I guess you can overload the control template to put in this kind of functionality and was wondering if anyone had any tips on how to proceed with that.